# how do I make Spring Schedulling to call a job with single tasklet periodically

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-scheduled

With the annotation `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 600000)`, I was expecting to trigger the job and, consequently, the tasklet as well, each 10 minutes (600000 milliseconds = 600 seconds = 10 minutes). Firstly, I tried by using `return RepeatStatus.FINISHED` since I understood the spring scheduler would trigger each 10 minutes an independent thread. In fact, if I use `return RepeatStatus.FINISHED`, it finishes the program at all, in other word, spring scheduler will not call the job again. 
I am not sure if I have setup something wrong in Spring Scheduler or I have some wrong concept in my mind about tasklet. As a rule of thumb, I have in my mind based on what I have studded recently, when I don't need a reader and writer method, tasklet is a possible alternative. I want to create a batch process which will just move file from one folder to other folder each ten minutes. There will be no file process.
From the console logs, I can see that the `TestScheduller.runJob` was evoked once when I ran `CommandLineJobRunner`.
Then, as my first investigation test, I changed to `return RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE` and, after that, I noted that the tasklet did ran infinite time but, instead of 10 minutes, let's say each 1 second. Certainly, this isn't correct. Additionally, the job didn't finish at all.
So, my question is: how can I make spring.schedulling evoke the below job each ten minutes?

Scheduler created in order to trigger the tasklet each 10 minutes:

```
@Component
public class TestScheduller {

       private Job job;
       private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

       @Autowired
       public TestScheduller(JobLauncher jobLauncher,
                     @Qualifier("helloWorldJob") Job job) {
              this.job = job;
              this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
       }

       @Scheduled(fixedRate = 600000) 
       public void runJob() {
              try {
                     System.out.println("runJob");
                     JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong(
                                  "time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

                     jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                     System.out.println("runJob exception ***********");
              }
       }
```

Java Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test.config")
@EnableScheduling
@Import(StandaloneInfrastructureConfiguration.class)
public class HelloWorldJobConfig {

       @Autowired
       private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilders;

       @Autowired
       private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders;

       @Autowired
       private InfrastructureConfiguration infrastructureConfiguration;

       @Autowired
       private DataSource dataSource; // just for show...

       @Bean
       public Job helloWorldJob(){
              return jobBuilders.get("helloWorldJob")
                           .start(step())
                           .build();


       }

       @Bean
       public Step step(){
              return stepBuilders.get("step")
                           .tasklet(tasklet())
                           .build();
       }

       @Bean
       public Tasklet tasklet() {
              return new HelloWorldTasklet();
       }
}
```

Tasklet:
    public class HelloWorldTasklet implements Tasklet {

```
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("HelloWorldTasklet.execute called");
        return RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE;
    }
}
```

Console Logs:

```
2016-01-18 14:16:16,376 INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@dcf3e99: startup date [Mon Jan 18 14:16:16 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-18 14:16:16,985 WARN  org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean Javadoc for complete details
2016-01-18 14:16:17,024 WARN  org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean Javadoc for complete details
2016-01-18 14:16:17,091 INFO  org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e07fa052] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-01-18 14:16:17,257 INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory - Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb', username='sa'
2016-01-18 14:16:17,425 INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql]
2016-01-18 14:16:17,430 INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql] in 5 ms.
2016-01-18 14:16:17,430 INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql]
2016-01-18 14:16:17,456 INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql] in 25 ms.
runJob
2016-01-18 14:16:18,083 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean - No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2016-01-18 14:16:18,103 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean - No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2016-01-18 14:16:18,448 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2016-01-18 14:16:18,454 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2016-01-18 14:16:18,558 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=helloWorldJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1453148177985}]
2016-01-18 14:16:18,591 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=helloWorldJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2016-01-18 14:16:18,613 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler - Executing step: [step]
HelloWorldTasklet.execute called
2016-01-18 14:16:18,661 INFO  org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=helloWorldJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2016-01-18 14:16:18,661 INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@dcf3e99: startup date [Mon Jan 18 14:16:16 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-18 14:16:18,665 INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory - Shutting down embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb'
2016-01-18 14:16:18,844 INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes;C:\PROGRA~2\HP\QUICKT~1\bin\JAVA_S~1\classes\jasmine.jar
```

Comment: I am regularly watching this question: any extra info expected, kindly, let me know it.

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue? if I set "FINISHED", it does not call the steps and repeats the cycle, if I set "CONTINUABLE", it just starts the job and freezes without going any further. Anyone, please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method setAllowStartIfComplete(true) of the TaskletStep. 
So instead of having a method like

```
@Bean
public Step step(){
    return stepBuilders.get("step")
                 .tasklet(tasklet())
                 .build();
}
```

it should look like:

```
@Bean
public Step step(){
    TaskletStep step = stepBuilders.get("step")
                 .tasklet(tasklet())
                 .build();
    step.setAllowSta
}
```